# Create a list like the outlook 2010 inbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a control that lists items, uses a collection of text and images in each item, can be scrolled though, titles given if re-ordered and can be selected.

The best example of this would be Microsoft Outlook 2010 inbox view with right reading pane.

I was hoping there would be something in the toolbox I could re-arrange to fit by needs? or would I have to build something myself? which would be a good challenge, but as I've not done this before I would like to avoid if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no .Net FW control out of the box for you. Either look for open source control / build on your own. FYI: I know this can be easily done in WPF world though.

Comment: thanks everyone, defiantly given me some new research material

Answer (score 0):

also check out TreeView and Custom TreeView for basic starters..

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to re-create if you didn't need it to be ordered.  For an off the shelf solution that you may be able to customize to your liking you should check out the DataTables plugin for jQuery.  http://datatables.net/